# Route trace using java

Tags: java, vaadin, openstreetmap

i want to trace the trajectory between differents points

for the test i creat points and try to link between these points

this is my code

```
     OpenStreetMapLayer osm = new OpenStreetMapLayer();


map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

List<Point>points= new ArrayList<Point>();

Point point = new Point(44.272872,4.27826);
Point point2 = new Point(-55.272873,5.3873837);
Point point3 = new Point(5.272873,54.3873837);

points.add(point);
points.add(point2);
points.add(point3);

Point[] coord=new Point[points.size()];
points.toArray(coord);

polyline.setPoints(coord);




vectorLayer.addComponent(polyline);

Style defaultstyle = new Style();
/* Set stroke color to green, otherwise like default style */
defaultstyle.extendCoreStyle("default");
defaultstyle.setStrokeColor("#0000ff");
defaultstyle.setStrokeWidth(3);
defaultstyle.setFillColor("#adfffc");
defaultstyle.setFillOpacity(0.4);

// Make borders of selected graphs bigger
Style selectStyle = new Style();
selectStyle.setStrokeWidth(5);

StyleMap stylemap = new StyleMap(defaultstyle, defaultstyle, null);
// make selectStyle inherit attributes not explicitly set
stylemap.setExtendDefault(true);
vectorLayer.setStyleMap(stylemap);
```

but when i execute my code i get just a point i've asked they told me this point is the point of cordinate(0,0)

this is the screen catch of the set of points without ZOOM (the blue point)
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/810776sss.png

and this is the MAX ZOOM
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/122823ert.png

i want to know if it is a probleme of scale or what?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPSG:4326 coords but OSM is using https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857.  The first one is in abs(180,90) where the second one is in in abs(6356752,6378137).  so your points are basically at the center in spherical mercator and zooming very close will give your result.  you have to convert your data e.g. using geotools